# Suspend resume Macbook pro

Tags: 12.04, suspend, macbook-pro

I'd like to start with sincere  congratulations to the Ubuntu team : got a macbook pro 6,2, and I confirm everything - including smooth install with rEfind- working very well on this machine. Keep on the good work !

If I could, the only missing thing not working is suspend to ram and resume. Sadly, it does break everything and produces a bad user experience.

Expected :

work, use the machine
close the lid  => the machine goes to sleep
(wait, do something else more than 5 minutes)
once back,open the lid
... wait some seconds
.. and continue to work.

Apple understood since a long time this IS ONE ESSENTIAL DIFFERENCES making people choose Mac OS X, and not Linux.

I know your devs do not have much time, but the main issue is not it does not work, but why it does not work ... and thus (not professional) devs like me could work on that.

BTW : I'm testing kernels, reading Intel gfx mailing list (and following fixes, since I'm a dev), playing with vgaswitcheroo and other things testing workarounds, even black magic, since 2 month without any success ( resume force me to reboot every time, because there is no more keyboard and other things)

Will you really fix the suspend resume on Macbook pro one day ?
Thanks in advance

-- 
ericb

Answer (score 1):

After some tries, it appears older kernel work, and suspend resume work as expected ( uff !).

For the record, 3.5.0, 3.5.7 and 3.6.11 are OK.
3.7.10 is not OK, and in some cases, resume does not work.

Important: if you use the link below, you do this at your own risks, and you perfectly know what you are doing 
Link for download: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

On the QA side, it appears that wrong changes appeared progressively, say since 3.6.x (one scary warning, the rest works) and things became wrong starting 3.7.x, but still work somewhat. Since 3.8.0 => no more resume. With the recent 3.9.0-rc6, one dev reproduced and analyzed the issue with resume, and found some interesting tracks.

To be continued ...

If you want to follow the development, see :
http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/intel-gfx/
And you'll understand how difficult things are ;-)

-- ericb

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with suspend on a macbook here's a solution that worked for me: https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=149965

More precisely:

```
1. open terminal: sudo nano /etc/default/grub
2. go to: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=" " and add to: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="init_on_alloc=0"
3. save and exit
4. sudo update-grub
5. reboot pc
```